# Apache storm configuration

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am facing an issue with setting isolation scheduler for a topology.
Basically I am trying to set number of machines to one topology as below.

```
Map<String, Number> topologyToMachines = new HashMap<String, Number>();
topologyToMachines.put(TOPOLOGY_NAME, 1);
config.put(Config.STORM_SCHEDULER, "backtype.storm.scheduler.IsolationScheduler");
config.put(Config.ISOLATION_SCHEDULER_MACHINES, topologyToMachines);
```

If I set like above, nimbus is not dedicating a node for this topology. I have set two workers for this topology. These two workers are assigned to two nodes instead of only one node.

But If I change configuration through `storm.yaml` in nimbus node and submit the same topology, only one node is assigned for this topology.

Is this a bug in Storm? I am using 0.9.1 version.

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour seems to be normal. Extract Storm 0.8.2 [release notes](https://storm.apache.org/2013/01/11/storm082-released.html) when Isolation Settings were added.

> Any topologies submitted to the cluster not listed there will not be isolated. Note that there is no way for a user of Storm to affect their isolation settings – this is only allowed by the administrator of the cluster (this is very much intentional).